# Fading out a signal in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

What is the most idiomatic way to produce a cumulative sum which "fades" out as it moves along. Let me explain with an example.

```
>>> np.array([1,0,-1,0,0]).cumsum()
array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
```

But I would like to provide a factor `<1` and produce something like:

```
>>> np.array([1,0,-1,0,0]).cumsum_with_factor(0.5)
array([1.0, 0.5, -0.75, -0.375, -0.1875], dtype=float64)
```

It's a big plus if it's fast!

Comment: Show us another sample case with more non-zeros, just to clarify?

Comment: What you are showing so far smells of "convolution" but as @Divakar rightly points out it would be good to see more examples.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: great advice, tried it and that was exactly what I was looking for! Write up and answer and I'll get you some points. :)

Comment: @PaulPanzer that is pretty cool! Convolution of `x[::-1]` with `[1, f, f^2, f^3, ..]`, right? Where did this intuition come from to you?

Comment: @BenUsman Oops, do I have to flip? Matrhematically, you should be right, but `numpy gives me the right answer without flipping... Re my intuition, just an educated guess I suppose. Convolution isn't entirely unheard of in signal processin ;).

Comment: @PaulPanzer `np.convolve`/convolution does the kernel flipping for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your result can be obtained by linear convolution:

```
signal = np.array([1,0,-1,0,0])
kernel = 0.5**np.arange(5)
np.convolve(signal, kernel, mode='full')
# array([ 1.    ,  0.5   , -0.75  , -0.375 , -0.1875, -0.125 , -0.0625,
          0.    ,  0.    ])
```

If performance is a consideration use `scipy.signal.fftconvolve` which is a faster implementation of the same logic.